# DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString returns NullPointerException in Android Kotlin Unit Test

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, junit5

I'm trying to write some simple unit tests for a utility function I wrote. I'm using JUnit5 and Kotlin. The test fails before finishing because a NullPointerException is thrown from DateUtil.getRelativeTimeSpanString(). I then added the @JvmStatic annotation but the NPE was still thrown.

Is is possible I need to mock something? I know these are in Android packages but I thought if you're only testing Java or Kotlin code then mocking is not necessary.

Test class:

```
import android.text.format.DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
internal class TimeSpanUtilsTest {

    @Test
    fun getRelativeTimeSpan() {
        val oneWeekAgo = System.currentTimeMillis() - WEEK_IN_MILLIS
        val result = TimeSpanUtils.getRelativeTimeSpan(oneWeekAgo)
        assertEquals("1 week ago", result)
    }
}
```

Utility function under test:

```
import android.text.format.DateUtils.*

object TimeSpanUtils {

    private enum class TimeResolution {
        MONTH_OR_MORE,
        WEEK,
        DAY,
        HOUR,
        MINUTE
    }

    /**
     *  Returns a readable relative time span from the current system time to the [from] time inputed.
     *  For example, if the time span is less than an hour but longer than a minute, then MINUTE_IN_MILLIS
     *  will be selected to input as the minResolution input for DateUtil's getRelativeTimeSpanString() method.
     */
    @JvmStatic
    fun getRelativeTimeSpan(from: Long): String {
        val to = System.currentTimeMillis()

        val minResolution = when (getTimeResolution(from, to)) {
            TimeResolution.MONTH_OR_MORE -> SECOND_IN_MILLIS
            TimeResolution.WEEK -> WEEK_IN_MILLIS
            TimeResolution.DAY -> DAY_IN_MILLIS
            TimeResolution.HOUR -> HOUR_IN_MILLIS
            TimeResolution.MINUTE -> MINUTE_IN_MILLIS
        }

        val relativeTimeSpan = getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            from,
            to,
            minResolution
        )

        return relativeTimeSpan.toString()
    }

    private fun getTimeResolution(from: Long, to: Long): TimeResolution {
        var diff = to - from
        if (diff < 0) diff *= -1

        val weeks = diff / WEEK_IN_MILLIS
        if (weeks > 4) return TimeResolution.MONTH_OR_MORE
        if (weeks >= 1 && weeks <= 4) return TimeResolution.WEEK

        val days = diff / DAY_IN_MILLIS
        if (days in 1..6) return TimeResolution.DAY

        val hours = diff / HOUR_IN_MILLIS
        return if (hours in 1..23) {
            TimeResolution.HOUR
        } else {
            TimeResolution.MINUTE
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

The test will pass if I place it in the androidTest package and run as an instrumented test. However, if I try to use Roboeletric, the test still fails as a unitTest. I'd prefer to keep the test as a unitTest.

Comment: Do you know which argument is `null`?

Comment: Also, fyi, `val weeks = diff / WEEK_IN_MILLIS` is integer division.

Comment: How do you run this test? Are you running it on a device or directly on your dev machine?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The test passes as an instrumented test on a device but I'd prefer to run as a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

You need instrumented tests (androidTest) to test code that uses Android APIs. Alternatively you can use Robolectric library to simulate Android environment in local tests.

Comment: Ok thank you, the test will pass and an NPE is not thrown when run as an instrumented test. But Roboelectric is not working in unitTest. A NPE is still thrown. I can't locate the cause of the NPE either because the error message comes back empty.